# Unity Script Compiling everytime I run the game

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, scripting

My Unity compiles scripts during runtime every time I run the game (Spinning compile icon indicator), even if I changed no code, it only occurs when I am using OS X and using the IOS platform.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a script processing the scene during runtime. It is located in Assets/Editor/UnityAds/UnityAdsBuildProcessor

I briefly commented it out.

Its content:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using UnityEditor.Advertisements;

public class UnityAdsBuildProcessor : Editor
{
    [PostProcessScene]
    public static void OnPostprocessScene ()
    {
        AdvertisementSettings.enabled = true;
        AdvertisementSettings.initializeOnStartup = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your class in "Editor" whether some editor class use compile cmd in runtime